# Convert Json format String to Link{"link":"https://i.imgur.com/zfxsqlk.png"}

Tags: python, json

I try to convert this String to only the link: `{"link":"https://i.imgur.com/zfxsqlk.png"}`

I'm trying to create a discord bot, which sends random pictures from the API `https://some-random-api.ml/img/red_panda`.

With `imageURL = json.loads(requests.get(redpandaurl).content)` I get the json String, but what do I have to do that I only get the Link like this `https://i.imgur.com/zfxsqlk.png`

Sorry if my question is confusingly written, I'm new to programming and don't really know how to describe this problem.

Comment: To get the only link try imageURL = json.loads(requests.get(redpandaurl).content)[“link”]

Comment: This is a pretty fundamental JavaScript data structure concept. [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN # *Objects and Properties*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties). I would recommend brushing up on all your JavaScript basics if this is something you aren’t yet comfortable with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
image_url = requests.get(your_api_url).json()["link"]
```

Directly use `requests.json()`, no need to load the string with `json.loads` and other manual stuff.

Answer (score 0):

What you get from json.loads() is a Python dict. You can access values in the dict by specifying their keys.
In your case, there is only one key-value pair in the dict: "link" is the key and "https://i.imgur.com/zfxsqlk.png" is the value. You can get the link and store it in the value by appending ["link"] to your line of code:
imageURL = json.loads(requests.get(redpandaurl).content)["link"]